# Ошибка при использовании конструктора

Tags: c++, visual-c++, перегрузка-операторов, c++17, перегрузка-функций

```
class Ctest
{
    public:
    int Dtest;
    Ctest (int _Dtest = 0 ) { Dtest = _Dtest; }
    void operator << (Ctest&);
}; 

void Ctest::operator << (Ctest& _Ctest)
{
    Dtest = _Ctest.Dtest;
};

Ctest _Ctest;

int main()
{
    _Ctest << Ctest(1);
}
```

оператор << не хочет работать, как заставить.

```
error C2679: бинарный "<<": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "Ctest" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)
message : может быть "void Ctest::operator <<(Ctest &)"
message : при попытке сопоставить список аргументов "(Ctest, Ctest)"
```

Comment: `(Ctest const & _Ctest)`

Answer (score 2):

В выражении

```
_Ctest << Ctest(1);
```

`Ctest(1)` это rvalue выражение. А дальше оно пытается вызвать перегруженный оператор <<, который принимает по ссылке. А обычная (lvalue) ссылка не может принять rvalue. Что делать? самый просто способ - сделать ссылку на константу

```
void Ctest::operator << (const Ctest& _Ctest)
{
    Dtest = _Ctest.Dtest;
};
```

или сделать вот такую перегрузку:

```
void Ctest::operator << (Ctest&& _Ctest)
{
    Dtest = _Ctest.Dtest;
};
```

Я бы делал `const&` и этого было бы достаточно. Но если объект "тяжелый" и для него можно написать хорошую функцию перемещения, то перегрузка и для rvalue - самое оно.

Comment: Большое спасибо, за ответ, чуть позже я планирую задать еще один подобный же вопрос, надеюсь на Вашу помощь.