# Ошибка при передаче параметров

Tags: c++, функции, visual-c++, const

```
class CMaiorTest;

class CMinorTest
{
public:
    int Dtest;
    CMinorTest(int i=0) { Dtest = i; };
    friend CMinorTest operator + (CMinorTest& _D1, CMinorTest _D2) { return CMinorTest(_D1+_D2); };
};

class CMaiorTest
{
public:
    CMinorTest CDtest;
    void Ftest(CMinorTest& D) { CDtest.Dtest += D.Dtest; };
};

CMinorTest Minor1, Minor2;
CMaiorTest Maior;

int main()
{
    Maior.Ftest(Minor1+Minor2);
}
```

код ошибки

```
error C2664: "void CMaiorTest::Ftest(CMinorTest &)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "CMinorTest" в "CMinorTest &"
message : Неконстантная ссылка может быть связана только с левосторонним значением
message : см. объявление "CMaiorTest::Ftest"
```

Comment: Ну такой же вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1322679/2739

Comment: Не ответ, но `_D1`, `_D2` - зарезервированные имена, т.к. начинаются с `_` и заглавной буквы. Лучше использовать что-то другое.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы избавиться от ошибки, о которой говорит компилятор, достаточно слова `const`:

```
void Ftest(const CMinorTest& D) { CDtest.Dtest += D.Dtest; };
```

Но!

```
friend CMinorTest operator + (CMinorTest& _D1, CMinorTest _D2) {
    return CMinorTest(_D1+_D2); 
};
```

Итак, у вас есть оператор `+`. Отлично. Что он делает? Возвращает результат суммирования. Для чего вызывает оператор `+`.

То есть **себя же**.

Который вызывает... Ну, вы поняли? Бесконечная рекурсия, Stack Overflow, только не на русском...

Я бы делал так:

```
friend CMinorTest operator + (const CMinorTest& _D1, const CMinorTest& _D2) { 
     return CMinorTest(_D1.Dtest+_D2.Dtest); 
};
```